# RecyclerView: need to ignore last scroll state

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` in bottom sheet. Every time I close and re-open the bottom sheet.

I would like the last `RecyclerView` scroll position to be ignored

> (it should always display with item 0 as the top fully visible item as
>   if it was opened for the first time).

The data is always the same so I don’t need to reload it.

Is there a better option to accomplish this than `scrollToPosition(0)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve your purpose by calling

```
RecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```

or

```
RecyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(0) ;
```

or as you said

```
RecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
```